# Content for the Assistant not working for "Now on tap"

Tags: android, google-now

I have a app which is showing some content of a URI, In-order to enable the Google's "Now on tap", I have override the

```
public void onProvideAssistContent(AssistContent assistContent) {

    assistContent.setWebUri(Uri.parse(https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1323&bih=673&q=rose&oq=rose&gs_l=img.3..0l10.1413.1946.0.2702.4.4.0.0.0.0.205.377.0j1j1.2.0....0...1ac.1.64.img..2.2.377.v1HZdEY5SDw"));

}
```

the URI consist to images search of rose on google. Then I long press the HOME key I am setting

> "Nothing to tap"

problem.

I have tried so after removing **FLAG_SECURE** also from my activity but still the problem remains the same.

My requirement is to show the Tap result for the URI I am passing to the overriden method.

Comment: Your code will not compile. Assuming you fix that, your use of `setWebUri()` does not seem to match [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/assist/AssistContent.html#setWebUri%28android.net.Uri%29). The `Uri` is supposed to represent your content. If I were Google, I would be specifically blocking URLs that might lead to random content, such as `google.com` search URLs. In general, it is up to Now On Tap to do what it wants with your content, which can include ignoring it.

Comment: @CommonsWare its compiling successful. I try to pas the URI for whcih i am fetching the content and customizing it on my display, So I though to pass the same URI to the framework. WHat do you suggest for my requirement.
i took the reference from Below block of code
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/android/java/src/org/chromium/chrome/browser/ChromeActivity.java&q=onProvideAssistContent&sq=package:chromium&l=747